# Add folder in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Can you create something similar to a folder in mongoose(or perhaps MongoDB)?
I've tried creating separate databases for each new so-called "folder" but it gets a bit tedious after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB is an object storage which does not store data in folder format. It stores them as documents, since it is a document-oriented datastore.

If you want a database or storage option resembling a folder, you might have to look into an object storage such as [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (cloud) or [MinIO](https://min.io/) (local).